# PureFTPd Server on OS X - FTP clients can login but unable to view or write to their folders

Tags: mac-osx, ftp, sftp

Need a real FTP guru for this one I think. If you know something about pureftp please read through the below logs and see if something jumps out at you. People can log in but not post files or make directories or view their previously put files.

Problem first reported 8:31 a.m. 5/5/14

> ftps://***.***.***.***:990 
>   OSX Server 10.5.8
>   Client Filezilla FTP client: Error: critical file transfer error 
>   Client Transmit on Mac when trying to create a directory error: Error -140: remote mkdir failed

Attempted stopping/starting ftp daemons, and restarted server but same result.
I did not build this system but I need to find out a resolution. Below are snippits of relevant log files. It is difficult to distinguish what is normal from abnormal but the error log in particular has a lot of concatenation

> 040xserve002:log admin$ sudo cat ftp.log
>
> May  5 15:40:32 040xserve002 pure-ftpd[2384]: (?@tardis.domain.com) [INFO] Logout.
>
> May  5 15:40:38 040xserve002 pure-ftpd[2392]: (?@tardis.domain.com) [INFO] New connection from tardis.domain.com
>
> May  5 15:40:39 040xserve002 pure-ftpd[2392]: (?@tardis.domain.com) [INFO] test.student is now logged in
>
> May  5 15:40:39 040xserve002 pure-ftpd[2392]: (test.student@tardis.domain.com) [INFO] Logout.

---

> 040xserve002:log admin$ sudo cat ftpswrap.log
>
> 2014-05-05 15:43:53,354: INFO: Connection from tardis.domain.com (10.52.27.75).
>
> 2014-05-05 15:43:54,039: INFO: Login from tardis.domain.com (10.52.27.75).

---

> 040xserve002:log admin$ cat ftpswrap-external.log
>
> 2014-05-05 15:30:17,953: INFO: Connection from tardis.domain.com (10.52.27.75).
>
> 2014-05-05 15:30:18,702: INFO: Login from tardis.domain.com (10.52.27.75).

---

You can see I attempted to connect and upload a file at 15:23:43.
The user that reported the problem, winrob..., posted files earlier.

> 040xserve002:log admin$ sudo cat homework-ftpd-client.2014-05.log

(This displays a connection where I was able to log in but not able to upload a file)

> [Mon May  5 15:23:33 2014][2239:-][CONNECTION FROM 127.0.0.1:53708] #1
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:43 2014][2239:-]USER coljas0614
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:43 2014][2239:coljas0614][UNRESTRICTED IP 127.0.0.1]
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:43 2014][2239:coljas0614]SYST
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:43 2014][2239:coljas0614]FEAT
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:43 2014][2239:coljas0614]OPTS UTF8 ON
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:43 2014][2239:coljas0614]PWD
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:43 2014][2239:coljas0614]TYPE I
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:43 2014][2239:coljas0614]PASV
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:43 2014][2239:coljas0614]MLSD
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:44 2014][2240:-][CONNECTION FROM 127.0.0.1:53714] #2
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:44 2014][2240:-]USER test.student
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:44 2014][2240:test.student][UNRESTRICTED IP 127.0.0.1]
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:44 2014][2240:test.student]QUIT
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:44 2014][2240:test.student][ENDED BY CLIENT 127.0.0.1:53714]
>
> [Mon May  5 15:23:54 2014][2239:coljas0614]PASV

THIS IS ME TRYING TO UPLOAD A FILE NAMED jasontest2

> [Mon May  5 15:23:54 2014][2239:coljas0614]STOR jasontest2
>
> [Mon May  5 15:24:00 2014][2239:coljas0614][ENDED BY CLIENT 127.0.0.1:53708]
>
> [Mon May  5 15:25:12 2014][2253:-][CONNECTION FROM 127.0.0.1:53741] #1

---

> 040xserve002:log admin$ sudo cat homework-ftpd-error.2014-05.log
>
> could not find student's student_id at /usr/local/ftp_homework/scripts/HomeworkFTP/Server.pm line 311,  line 2.
>    at /Library/Perl/5.8.8/Net/FTPServer.pm line 2353,  line 2.
>       Net::FTPServer::**ANON**('could not find student\'s student_id at /usr/local/ftp_homewo...') called at /usr/local/ftp_homework/scripts/HomeworkFTP/Server.pm line 311

```
>Net::FTPServer::HomeworkFTP::Server::user_login_hook('Net::FTPServer::HomeworkFTP::Server=HASH(0x801794)', 'test.student', undef) called at /Library/Perl/5.8.8/Net/FTPServer.pm line 4662
Net::FTPServer::_PASS_command('Net::FTPServer::HomeworkFTP::Server=HASH(0x801794)', 'PASS', 'test') called at /Library/Perl/5.8.8/Net/FTPServer.pm line 3002
Net::FTPServer::run('Net::FTPServer::HomeworkFTP::Server') called at /usr/local/ftp_homework/scripts/homework-ftpd.pl line 34
```

> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /Library/Perl/5.8.8/Net/FTPServer.pm line 5905,  line 21, line 26, line 30... through line 1006...

---

> 040xserve002:log admin$ sudo cat homework-ftpd-xfer.2014-05.log
>
> Fri May  2 12:12:37 2014 0 127.0.0.1 126 / a _ o r burbru0525 ftp 0 * c
>
> Fri May  2 12:14:29 2014 0 127.0.0.1 126 / a _ o r burbru0525 ftp 0 * c
>
> Mon May  5 11:35:26 2014 1 127.0.0.1 258 / a _ o r burbru0525 ftp 0 * c
>
> Mon May  5 11:35:29 2014 0 127.0.0.1 417 /PTT214-VA/ a _ o r burbru0525 ftp 0 * c

...

> Mon May  5 12:34:35 2014 0 127.0.0.1 126 / a _ o r yawban0510 ftp 0 * c
>   Mon May  5 12:54:52 2014 0 127.0.0.1 258 / a _ o r winrob0319 ftp 0 * c

---

> 040xserve002:etc admin$ sudo cat /var/log/pureftpd.log

...

> 2014-03-31 23:35:12 10.54.32.89 []created /Volumes/Storage%20HD/ftp/8888/chad%20hill%20%2811B5640342%29/hill_chad_ceremony_2.jpg 226 c.hill135 724587
>
> 2014-03-31 23:50:22 10.54.32.89 []created /Volumes/Storage%20HD/ftp/8888/chad%20hill%20%2811B5640342%29/hill_chad_ceremony_3.jpg 226 c.hill135 446325

Comment: Please spend a few minutes reading http://serverfault.com/editing-help , then reformat your post so it's actually readable. While you're doing so, consider trimming the massive info dump down to *the **relevant** details* (just dumping your entire log file on us and expecting the community to dig through it is exceptionally poor form). Once you've done that this post may be reopened.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Editing has been done and I think it's viewable now. Can you please re-open?

Comment: Much better - thanks :-) (Sorry it took so long to reopen, I was AFK for much of the evening) - On looking at it this *appears* to be a bug in the FTP server (perl program?) that you're using - at least based on the log snippet you posted. If this is something you're writing we can migrate this to Stack Overflow (and you can add the code there - they could help you sort out what's up, but it looks like it's trying to look up an ID, failing, and then passing `undef` around...)

Answer (score 0):

ran the following on the ftp servers to resolve successfully:

> sudo /Library/StartupItems/FTPSWRAP/FTPSWRAP restart
>
> sudo /usr/local/sbin/homework-ftpd-init restart
>
> sudo /Library/StartupItems/PureFTPD/PureFTPD restart